# How to highlight list of words in vim

Tags: vim

I have a commnad "com" witch produces list of words on stdout

```
w1
w2
w3
...
```

I need a vim function, that can execute my command, read the list and highlight all words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example which worked for me:

```
for word in split(system("cat words.txt"), "\n")
    call matchadd("Search", word)
endfor
```

This can be wrapped in a function (with replaced the program call with `com`):

```
fun MakeMatches()
    for word in split(system("com"), "\n")
        call matchadd("Search", word)
    endfor
endfun
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use a single call to `matchadd` rather then add multiple matches as they should be slower and also take care about the situation when you call function for the second time:

```
function DelMatches()
    if exists('s:matchnr')
        try
            call matchdelete(s:matchnr)
        catch /\V\^Vim(call):E803:/
            " Ignore `ID not found' error
        endtry
        unlet s:matchnr
    endif
endfunction
function MakeMatches()
    call DelMatches()
    let s:matchnr=matchadd("Search", '\V\<\%('.join(map(split(system("com"), "\n"), 'escape(v:val, "\\")'), '\|').'\)\>')
endfunction
```